# Flutter single radio button

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

How to make a single radio button like the image below.

[image: Button model I want]

This is what I tried. Anyone can help?

```
RadioListTile(
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    ///use your image
                    CountryFlags.flag(
                      'bh',
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      borderRadius: 5,
                    ),
                    Text("  Bahrain"),
                  ],
                ),
                value: "Bahrain",
                groupValue: "bahrain",
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Can you explain more what your issue is? What does it look like and what is not working?

Comment: A "single radio button" would be always on.  A radio is expected to be a part of a "one of many" selection.  Perhaps what you are looking for instead is a checkbox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `MainAxisAlignment.center`

```dart
RadioListTile(
  tileColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
  title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      ///use your image
      Icon(Icons.flag),
      Text(
        "Bahrain",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you! How to change the button background and text color?

Comment: You can use `tileColor` and `testStyle`